# Where does character pointer resides in memory, ROM or RAM?

Tags: ram, rom

I am running Embedded C on some ARM Cortex-M4 target which facilitates with both ROM and RAM support. I have a character pointer in my code:

```
char *temp = "";
```

Later in code I am modifying the variable as:

```
itoa(some_integer, temp, 10);
```

When I compile the code, compiler puts *temp in ROM section which cause exception to raise when trying to perform itoa(,,) operation as constant variable can not be modified. **My question is that why compiler is putting char *temp into ROM section**?

Comment: ... Because it's a string literal, and string literals should not be modified.

Comment: And this is a question for StackOverflow. Which will get closed as 1 zillions duplicate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about C programming, with no specific application to electronics.

Comment: I don't think you really understand how strings work in C. Even if the compiler allowed you to do that, you'd probably be overwriting some other variable's memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is that why compiler is putting char *temp into ROM section?

It's not. If you don't believe me, try this `temp = NULL;`. That will execute just fine, proving that `temp` was stored in RAM, not ROM. Because `temp` is a variable, you are free to change its value.

What was stored in ROM was `""`, an empty string. Since the value of `""` can't change, just as the value of 3 can't change, it makes sense to store it in ROM.

So what's wrong with:

```
itoa(some_integer, temp, 10);
```

At this point, `temp` points to the string literal `""`. You are trying to change the thing `temp` points to. But literals are constants, and `temp` points to a constant. So you are trying to change a constant. But you can't change a constant -- that's what makes it constant.

So, `temp` is a variable, and you can change its value. But it points to a constant. So you can't change the value of the thing it points to.

Comment: Fine explanation, and because it relates to low-level C aspects I think it isn't out of place on EE SE.

Comment: With a toolchain targeted for embedded systems, it would not be unusual to actually define the [section](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_mono/ld.html#SEC18) you want your variable to reside in by an __attribute__-directive and to use a custom linker script to define placement in ROM,DRAM,SRAM, ...whatever. So it's completely up to you where things end up.